# How to run a single job on 2 different executors in parallel?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have a Jenkins job configured and 2 different build executors configured in Jenkins. I need to run a single job on these 2 executors. Can somebody help me how to proceed for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This solution only works in scripted pipelines (and maybe in declarative as well)

```
def pipeline = {
    //your complete pipeline code here
}

node('one'){
    pipeline()
}

node('two'){
    pipeline()
}
```

It's not perfect, but the DRYest solution I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works in scripted pipelines.

```
stage('Deploy') {
   parallel {

   stage('ECS node-1 Deploy') {    
   steps {    
       sh label: 'node-1 Deploy',
       script: """
               set +x;
               if [ "${params.node-1}" = true ] ; then
                    /usr/local/jenkins-scripts/ecs_deploy.sh node-1-service ${cluster_name}
                fi 
               """
       }
       }

   stage('ECS node-2 Deploy') {    
   steps {    
       sh label: 'node-2 Deploy',
       script: """
               set +x;
               if [ "${params.node-2}" = true ] ; then
                    /usr/local/jenkins-scripts/ecs_deploy.sh node-2-service ${cluster_name}
                fi 
               """
       }
      }
     }
```